# What is the order of time series analysis techniques?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

When approaching a given time series for analysis, I understand there are certain tools/techniques/formulas that can be applied to gain further understanding, namely:

1. Tests for stationarity and for unit root
2. Decomposition (additive or multiplicative)
3. Lag plots and autocorrelation function
4. Desonalization and detrending

I've read that these are some simple techniques and can have insights to the data that are similar, but what order should I be doing them in? Ideally, is there some kind of decision flow chart for this process?

Comment: What is the goal? Forecasting? something else ? ... One series or multiple series? ... I thini this is maybe to unfocused, you need to focus it more.